# python:curses freezes in IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, ide, curses

I was trying to learn about the curses.I imported the `curses` module and started to work in the IDE.After setting `curses.initscr` to the variable stdscr the IDLE suddenly freezes.I did it just like this:

```
>>> import curses
>>> stdscr = curses.initscr()
```

Then the IDE just freezed.Could anyone explain what had just happen.And how can I avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curses module only run on Unix with a fixed-pitch font, rows and columns, text terminal or a graphics window that emulates a text terminal.  Idle executes user code in a no-terminal process and displays results in its tk graphics window Shell.  The two are not compatible and I suspect the same would be true of any graphics IDE unless the IDE noticed 'import curses' and ran the program in a special mode.

My advice is to edit your code in Idle or any other editor and then run the code at the command line of your text-mode console window.  For instance

```
.../mydir> python try_curses.py
```

where mydir is the directory containing your file.